# Silence the [silent] questions

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I ran into [silent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/silent) with this question: [How can I silently send Outlook email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760801/how-can-i-silently-send-outlook-email)

To me it reads as a meta tag. It is on present on about 240 questions.

Comment: On seeing this post, I immediately checked if a JS library named "silent" exists and I was not disappointed.

Comment: @approxiblue example?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/silent None of the questions in the tag is about this, fortunately.

Comment: @approxiblue: Clearly, anyone who has problems with that library just stays silent. ... I'll show myself out.

Comment: there are questions about non-interactive ("silent") installations as well as applications. What should the tag be replaced with? Or should it? non-interactive seems like a meta tag as well. [47 questions tagged with that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-interactive). [867 with interactive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interactive).

Comment: i agree those 2 also seem meta.

Comment: [silent] Green is people! We've gotta stop them somehow!

Comment: There might be case to be made for silent [un]installs. But these questions need to be hand-edited, not dealt with in bulk. Please do so slowly, so as not to create a DOS attack on my homepage.

Comment: Let's make this tag [silent]